# screen inside systemd wants 777 permissions on /run/screen but 775 outside

Tags: permissions, systemd, gnu-screen

I am trying to run an application as a **systemd** service inside a **screen** container.

When trying to start the service it fails with the error message:

```
screen[11648]: Directory '/run/screen' must have mode 777.
```

It looks like a simple error with a simple solution. When I change the permissions of `/run/screen` accordingly the service starts without problem.

But now when I try to attach the screen session (or run `screen` in any way as a normal user or as root) I get the error message.

```
Directory '/run/screen' must have mode 775.
```

Changing permissions obviously lets me run into the first error again and from there I could play cat and mouse with screen all day.

```
Screen version 4.05.00 (GNU) 10-Dec-16
```

The operating system is **Debian 9** (server).

**Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? In any case, how do I get it to work?**

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to setup a minecraft server under systemd on Debian 9. No fix that I know of but here's a partial work-around. I added these lines to the unit configuration file:

```
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 777 /run/screen
```

So this will adjust the permissions as needed for the service to start. And I can set the permissions back to 775 whenever I need to use screen for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Change `NoNewPrivileges=true` to `NoNewPrivileges=false` (or add that line if it doesn't exist in the `[Service]` section).  This will allow screen to run in setgid mode, like it usually does, so it won't ask for 777 permissions.